# Make final <li> in list span remaining container width?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have several `<li>` elements in an unordered list.  All but the last `<li>` have a JS/dynamically assigned width.  I want the final `<li>` width to take up the remaining space, completely filling the entire window width.

[This JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/14/) has everything except for the final `<li class="three">` taking up the remaining width of the window.  How do I achieve this? Browser compatibility (older IE, etc) is not a concern here, but I would like to aim for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you want.
Here is a simple suggestion using jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    var width = parseInt($(document).width()) - parseInt($('li').width()) -
                parseInt($('li:first').width());
    $("li:last").css("width",width);
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/24/).

Comment: This doesn't work as expected -- try resizing the browser window smaller, or drag the bars on the fiddle UI. I also was hoping for a CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive by giving width to each li in %

```
<ul>
<li class="one" style="width:25%">One</li>
<li class="two" style="width:25%">Two</li>
<li class="three" style="width:50%">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to set the width manually -- I was hoping for a CSS solution that automatically made the final `<li>` span the remaining width.  Since there will be N number of `<li>` I won't be able to set this as you've shown.

Comment: You can apply seperate class for each li as you are applying (one, two, three) so give width in percentage for each li. you know the width of other li?

Comment: No, they are generated dynamically, and may change through JS.  Is there no way to have the final `<li>` to always take up the remaining space inside the parent container?

Comment: You can do this using jquery $('li').last().css('width', '50%'); you can search on it.

Comment: Argh, no you're missing the point.  I need this width to be handled automatically by CSS.  I don't want to have to explicitly pass a width as an integer/float.